# Database connection in my webhost home directory

Tags: php, sql, linux, database, cron

I am having an issue related to `cron job` and accessing database connection in my home directory.

Actually in my cron job I have given the commend to send mails to all the new users and new users are fetched from the database

The file which sends the mail has something like this

```
 <?php include_once('connection_database.php');
 //$to='anything';
 //$from anything ......
 //$headers 
 //mail (......);
 //database connection is not available here 
 //the file is not in public_html it is in user/home/mails/cronjobs
  ?>
```

Everything is good except that the page doesn't have database connection actually the file is not in public_html directory it is in user/home/mails/cronjobs
directory.

Seems like this page doesn't have any database connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the location of the file, like this:

```
<?php include_once('/home/mails/cronjobs/connection_database.php');
    ...
     //the file is not in public_html it is in user/home/mails/cronjobs
?>
```

Make sure you have access to that directory as some hosting providers might only allow you to have access to the public_html directory...

Comment: Then you are not specifying the path correctly, or the file is not there, or as I said, you **`don't have permissions`** to access that folder.

Answer (score 1):

change the path to your database conection

```
include_once('/path/to/the/file/connection_database.php');
```

EDIT:

Why you don't put your php file in the same directory where is your connection_database.php. Then in your bash file write:

```
php  /path/to/your/file/file.php
```

and call your script from the console to check the result